# Sql about find rate is less then 9 and star name

Tags: sql

Find every time a student paid 9 or less to see a movie starring Will Smith. Print all the relevant information; order by the name of the student (desc) and then the name of the movie.

there is two table one is call films has student name and amount_paid, movie_name and rate. another table name is movies, has movie_name and star.

```
Select star, movie_name, amount_paid, rate,
From movies
Where amount_paid < = 9
having star = 'will smith'
Order by student_name desc;

films

STUDENT_NAME               MOVIE                      AMOUNT_PAID       RATE
-------------------------- -------------------------- ----------- ----------
Jack                       Noah                                12          5
Jet                        The Professional                    24         10
Lincoln                    The Weather Man                     10        4.5
Smith                      Despite the Falling Snow             9        3.5
River                      The Weather Man                    2.5        4.5
PHIL                       FORREST GUMP                        18          9
Dave                       Legend                              18          8

movies
MOVIE_NAME                 STAR
-------------------------- --------------------------
Noah                       Russell Crowe
Legend                     will smith
```

Comment: If you get an error message do three things.  `1.` Read it.  `2.` Google it if you don't understand it.  `3.` Include it in your question if you ask on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra comma at the end of line one, and a gap between `<` and `=`.

Although trailing commas is okay in JSON, etc, it causes syntax errors in SQL.

And `< =` instead of `<=` is likely to break every programming language.

```
Select star, movie_name, amount_paid, rate   -- removed a comma
From movies
Where amount_paid <= 9                       -- removed a space
and star = 'will smith'
Order by student_name desc;
```

**EDIT:**

As this is from two tables...

```
SELECT
  movies.STAR,
  movies.MOVIE_NAME,
  films.STUDENT_NAME,
  films.AMOUNT_PAID,
  films.RATE
FROM
  films
INNER JOIN
  movies
    ON movies.MOVIE_NAME = films.MOVIE
WHERE
      films.RATE <= 9
  AND movies.STAR = 'will smith'
ORDER BY
  films.STUDENT_NAME DESC
```

Comment: i add table, the way you did is not right, them are two tables

Comment: sorry, I tried this answer, but it shows films.movie is invalid identifier

Comment: @YongmingLiu - Then you need to check that your `films` table actually has a `movie` column.  *(Hint: You possible copied it wrong, and it's probably called `MOVIE_NAME`, in which case change all `films.MOVIE` to `films.MOVIE_NAME`)*

Comment: even I check my table and change to movie_name, it still has an error, but I think you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT
  movies.STAR,
  movies.MOVIE_NAME,
  films.STUDENT_NAME,
  films.AMOUNT_PAID,
  films.RATE
FROM
  films,
  movies
where
films.movie=movies.movie_name
and films.AMOUNT_PAID>=9
order by films.STUDENT_NAME,movies.movie_name
```

Comment: i add table, the way you did is not right, they are two tables